# Show top 3 from list based on difference

Tags: excel

I have 2 lists;

```
"yesterday" and "today".
```

As rows I have a list of companies and the data shown is customer satisfaction going from 0-10. I want to show the top 3 companies that has the best difference between "`yesterday`" and "`today`".

How would you approach this??

Expected output looking for top 1:

Yesterday     -     Today 
Company A:        5                     10

Company B:        7                      8
Company C:        8                      6

Top 1: Company A (Since they moved the most(5 positive points))

Comment: Please provide sample data with expected output.

Comment: @PareshJ I added expected out, do you know if is possible with a formula and not VBA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your data is like this:

```
#########Sheet1<YESTERDAY>########
 |    A    |          B           |
1|Companies| Customer satisfaction|
2|Company1 |         6
3|Company2 |         3
4|Company3 |         4
5|Company4 |         1
6|Company5 |         9


###########Sheet2<TODAY>##########
 |    A    |          B           |       C         |     D      |
1|Companies| Customer satisfaction|Absolute changes |    RANK    |
2|Company1 |         1            |                 |            |
3|Company2 |         7            |                 |            |
4|Company3 |         7            |                 |            |
5|Company4 |         4            |                 |            |
6|Company5 |         8            |                 |            |
```

Put this formula into Cell `C2`to get absolute change:

```
=ABS(VLOOKUP(A2,YESTERDAY!$A$2:$B$6,2,FALSE)-B2)
```

Put this formula into Cell `D2`to get Rank:

```
=RANK(C2,$C$2:$C$6,0)
```

So, 1,2,3 in Column RANK are best changes.

Answer (score 0):

I assume best difference as highest difference.run a loop and take the first row company from **yesterday** as well as the customer satisfaction value and search that same company in **today** in another inner loop and find the difference of the two values and save it in an array.After that sort the array and display the top 3.